# setuptools / dpkg-buildpackage: Refuse to build if nosetests fail

Tags: python, debian, setuptools, nose, cdbs

I have a very simple python package that I build into debian packages using setuptools, cdbs and pycentral:

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='PHPSerialize',
  version='1.0',
  py_modules=['PHPSerialize'],
  test_suite = 'nose.collector'
 )
```

debian/rules:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
DEB_PYTHON_SYSTEM = pycentral

include /usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/debhelper.mk
include /usr/share/cdbs/1/class/python-distutils.mk
```

Now, is there an easy way to make dpkg-buildpackage execute the unit tests and refuse to create the .deb if the test suite fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
build/yourpackage::
         nosetests
```